# How to Provide an "Exit" Menu Item

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, exit

How can one program a program close ("Exit") item on a menu? So to close the wpf window when clicked?

Comment: Do you actually mean `winforms` by `wpf`? I would like to re-edit your question (replace the `wpf` with `winforms` and re-tag it).

Comment: That's not the same question as the one linked as a reason for closing this question. Although this question overlaps the topic in the linked question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WPF comes has a control which is `Menu`. One adds `MenuItem` elements to a `Menu`, and each `MenuItem` can have a range of sub-items, hence allowing for the creation of hierarchical menus.

### Example

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
</DockPanel>
```

## Code Behind

```
 private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
 }
```